# Regular express read from right to left

Tags: php, regex

I want to read string from right to left. For example I want to get `50940775` from `$game` in below code.

I referred another stackoverflow question. They said to use `$`, but it is not working for me. I use below code.

```
$game = 'http://www.myspace.com/sdsf/1223232/videos/video/50940775black';

preg_match('/\/(.*?)black$/', $game, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Note : `$game Url` are different like below

```
http://www.myspace.com/sdsf/1223232/black/video/50940775black
http://www.myspace.com/sdsf/1223232/videos/12345/50940775black
http://www.myspace.com/sdsf/1223232/videos/games129kj/5675999black
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to get numbers, you can specify that you only want them (`[0-9]+`) instead of every thing (`.*`). With `.*` it will retrieve every thing between the first `/` found and `black`. So, in your case: `/www.myspace.com/sdsf/1223232/videos/video/50940775black`

Try this one:

```
$game = 'http://www.myspace.com/sdsf/1223232/videos/video/50940775black';

preg_match('/\/([0-9]+)black$/', $game, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

[Live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LqTvYu).

**Edit:**

In fact, it's hard to read from right to left. What you can do is explode the url by `/` and then use the last part to apply your regex:

```
<?php

$game = explode('/', 'http://www.myspace.com/sdsf/1223232/videos/video/50940775black');
$data = end($game);

preg_match('/(.*?)black$/', $data, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use `@` as a regex delimiter

Comment: I want to get clue from http://www.myspace.com/video/gameblack/1223232/videos/video/clueblack

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead:

```
$game = 'http://www.myspace.com/sdsf/1223232/videos/video/50940775black';
preg_match('/\/([^\/]+)black$/', $game, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Why wasn't it working before? It has to do with the nature of greediness. The non-greedy operator does not cause the regex to find the shortest possible match in the string. It finds the *first* match that doesn't contain any other matches. If you take the match it found and you start backtracking, you would never find another substring that matches that string **from the beginning of the match it found first**. It's a subtle difference.

While writing this, I see someone recommended looking for just numbers. That will work, too, as long as you're sure what is there will be just numbers.  If your purpose is to grab whatever is between the closest `/` and `black`, then the regex targets that exactly.